# Jmeter to connect to IBM MQ

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

I am doing an IBM webpshere project and IBM MQ is reauired within this project, and now, We need to use Jmeter to send message to IBM MQ,

Anyone knows how to create the test plan in Jmeter for IBM MQ message test? link and test plan are preferred.

Note, IBM MQ is a little difference with standard JMS, it provides host, queue manager, server channel, port and queue name, how can we configure this within Jmeter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

1. Follow instructions from [Obtaining the WebSphere MQ classes for JMS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398) guide to get all the necessary client libraries.
2. Place libraries from step 1 to JMeter classpath using one of following approaches:

   - add jars to /lib folder of JMeter installation
   - add the next line to *user.properties* file

     user.classpath=/folder/with/mq/jars

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the libraries up.
3. Follow steps from [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) guide to set JMeter up.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, for step 3, if we connect to JMS queue, we can create a test plan like this. But as you know, for Websphere MQ, there is no connection factory, what Websphere MQ provides is host, Queue Manager, Port, server channel, and queue name. how can we configure this in JMeter?

Comment: Of course there is a JMS connection factory for MQ: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory, which is in the MQ JMS classes Dmitri is referencing in the 1. step. You can configure it to connect to a queue manager, using a specific host, port, and server connection channel.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mqmeter](https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/mqmeter) Java Sampler Request:

https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/mqmeter

I used it and works very well.

If you have questions or comments let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You should read the [JMeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html). It has a whole section on build a JMS test plan.

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for your answer, as I said above, Websphere MQ is difference with standard JMS, it provides host, queue manager, port,server channel and queues,how can we configure this within jmeter?

Comment: Does not provide any help, just refer to the Jmeter manual which is not a viable solution for interact with IBM MQ.

Comment: The manual of any product should always be the _**first**_ place a user looks for details on how to perform particular function/feature of said product.  Why do you not think that people for decades have said RTM (Read The Manual).  StackOverflow should be the 4th place a user looks for information.  (1) RTM, (2) A company's forum specific to the product, (3) Google search and finally (4) posting of a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: As I said, the manual doesn't help and point to the manual does not a valid answer to the user. Doesn't solve the problem.