# Error in IBM MQ / LoadRunner JMS

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, jndi, loadrunner

I am trying to send messages to IBM MQ through LoadRunner JMS, but getting the below exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.getObjectFromBindings(RefFSContext.java:400)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookupObject(RefFSContext.java:327)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.ConnectionManagerImpl.initialize(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:99)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.JMSSupportImpl.initialize(JMSSupportImpl.java:28)
    at com.mercury.ws.jms.JMSBridge.init_jms(JMSBridge.java:154)
```

Comment: Is JMeter tag relevant here?

Comment: if not, edit your question and remove it

Comment: Do you have `fscontext.jar` and `providerutil.jar`?  Have you confirmed the name you are specifying is a valid JNDI name in the bindings file?

Comment: Since this is a NameNotFoundException and not a ClassNotFoundException, I suspect it's something with the name of JNDI object to lookup ? What is your configuration set to ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting some .jars

There is an [MQ JAR file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398) called 'com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar', it can help you.

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361577/how-to-resolve-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-com-ibm-mq-jms-mqqueueconnect) are solving this issue, read about that.

Comment: I have referred the link already & add the jar files, still no luck