# Connect to an MQ with Jmeter, and provide a return address

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, ibm-mq

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832345/connecting-to-an-mq-with-jmeter/49856440), the requirements have evolved. No longer is it enough to send a message to the mq. I must now include a "return address" in the message. I'm given to understand that this will include some information on an MQ I control (but which, annoyingly enough, I haven't been given access to just yet). My question is: what information will I need from 'my' MQ, and how do I include it in the message I send, so that the MQ on the other side will send a dummy response to the correct return address?

Comment: Please post the code you use to send the message.   Is it exactly like the answer by dimity t?   Confirm you just have the jar files and connect to a queue manager v that you spoke of.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Return routing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q015460_.htm) IBMMQ knowledge base article:

> Messages can contain a return address in the form of the name of a queue and queue manager. This return address form can be used in both a distributed-queuing environment and a clustering environment.
>
> This address is normally specified **by the application that creates the message**. It can be modified by any application that then handles the message, including user exit applications.
>
> Irrespective of the source of this address, any application handling the message **might choose to use this address for returning answer**, status, or report messages to the originating application.
>
> The way these response messages are routed is not different from the way the original message is routed. You need to be aware that the message flows you create to other queue managers need corresponding return flows.

IBMMQ message format is not specified (apart from very [generic types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q091470_.htm)), it is totally up to developer so you need to ask your developers regarding what you should use as the return address, or if you have a requirement to test responses routing - you should know the queue manager and the queue name yourself.

If you don't have an IBMMQ instance to play with you can easily get one up and running using i.e. [IBMMQ Docker Container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/), check out [Testing “Docked” IBM MQ with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/testing-docked-ibmmq-with-jmeter-learn-how) article for comprehensive configuration instructions.