# Is there any reference Document for Integrating Citrus frame work with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, citrus-framework

Hi I want to do Load test for JMS MQ using Citrus frame work integrating with Jmeter for performance test.Is there any document  please refer me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you test your MQ Series directlty with JMeter without using Citrus Framework? JMeter Plugins are available for this use case ([Jmeter to connect to IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278071/jmeter-to-connect-to-ibm-mq)).

Comment: Yeah, MatLoub Thanks for your  response. I used Jmeter for  MQ series loadTest and integrated with citrus frame work.

Answer (score -1):

- List item

1.Initially, We have to run JMS loadtest script in jmeter and if it works fine we have to save that Script in .JMX (example:jmsloadtest.jmx)

2.By invoking that .jmx file  using java we can execute load test without using Jmeter.
for reference[invoking .jmx file with java](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

3.Now we can use this class as a function  in citrus frame work.for that have follow custom functions in citrus framework document.

Thank you.