# How to send MQ messages (JMS) using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, mq

I have to put messages in a queue for which I have all the connection details (host, port, channel, manager, queuename and username). I never worked on implementing JMeter for sending MQ. Can anyone let me know where can I get (blog or reference) step by step procedure to perform this? I tried referring to official site, can't really understand those JNDI, connection Factory settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jmeter to connect to IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278071/jmeter-to-connect-to-ibm-mq)

Comment: Sounds like you are using IBM MQ.  This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278071/jmeter-to-connect-to-ibm-mq

Answer (score 0):

Man, your `MQ` statement is too general as there are too many possible message queue system providers like Apache ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, IBM MQ, TIBCO, etc. and the values for all these JNDI/JMS properties, connection factory names, queue names, etc. will be different.

1. To get an overview of Java communication with "MQ" get familiarized with [Getting Started with Java Message Service (JMS)](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/intro-java-message-service.html)
2. Download .jar files for your MQ system and put them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
3. Perform configuration as per your MQ system connection settings, example setup for Apache ActiveMQ is here: [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)